# cancell common factors

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

p³ - PQ²
--------- Divided by
(P+Q)²

Apparently the answer is

P(P-Q)
--------- Divided by
P+Q

But how?
- What I was thinking
P-P (P-Q), (P+Q)
------------------ Divided by
(P+Q)

which is

P-P (P-Q)
------------Divided by
(P+Q)

How is it that 4p's become 2 p's? Please answer step by step.

Comment: $$\frac{P^3-PQ^2}{(P+Q)^2}=\frac{P(P^2-Q^2)}{(P+Q)^2}=\frac{P(P-Q)\color{Red}{(P+Q)}}{(P+Q)\color{Red}{(P+Q)}}=\frac{P(P-Q)}{P+Q}.$$ This is not linear algebra, numerical linear algebra, abstract algebra, or algebraic topology.

Answer (score 2):

$$\require{cancel}\frac{P^3-PQ^2}{(P+Q)^2}=\frac{P(P^2-Q^2)}{(P+Q)^2}=\frac{P(P-Q)\cancel{(P‌​+Q)}}{(P+Q)\cancel{(P+Q)}}=\frac{P(P-Q)}{P+Q}$$

Comment: When you copy another user's prior comment into your answer (as is clear from examining the TeX code), you should at least acknowledge the source (and, more nobly, post your answer as CW).